# Iframe redirection issue on session timeout in JSF

Tags: iframe, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 along with RichFaces. In my XHTML file I'm using `iframe`.

The session is kept in such a way that same tags of the browser holds same session. But session can be invalidated while taking in another browser. My problem is that when the session gets invalidated `iframe` is not redirected to login page and I'm getting `ViewExpiredException`.

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with redirection. `send.redirect()` method redirects to my login page, but the login page comes inside the `iframe` page.

So I used `form.submit()` which submits the page and hence the XHTML comes out of the `iframe` in same page.